# Writing rows on top of a data frame /csv file (Merging set of lists to a dataframe)

Tags: pandas, csv, header, concatenation, writer

I want to merge a set of lists saved as a tuple called "rows" on top dataframe (df) that I have created:

```
Lat = '31.513'
Lon = '-84.034'
Panel = 'Jinko 395'
AxisTilt =  'Tracking 0'
Azimuth = '180'

rows = ['Lat: ' +  Lat + ' ; ' + 'Lon: ' + Lon], ['Panel', Panel], ['Axis Tilt', AxisTilt, 'degrees' ], ['Azimuth', Azimuth, 'degrees' ], [],  ['Sum of Power']

df = ["Hour", "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Hour Average"]
```

**Desired Output:** 
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you have sample data sets and expected results, it will be helpful for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I had *df* as last item of *rows*. I suggest :

```
import pandas as pd

d = dict((i, rows[i]) for i in range(len(rows)))
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').fillna('')
```